# Python data extraction version 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

*edit*
Version of the IOS, name of the router, IP host addresses, ethernet port and serial port IP addresses. Are the things I need to extract from the text file
*edit*

I posted a Python related question earlier and I didn't give enough information or anything for you guys to work with. I'm trying to extract data from a text file. Copy and paste the text on the following link if you want the exact text file. http://content.hccfl.edu/dalemabry/dpt/cs/cisco/current/laba.htm

The problem I'm running into is my lack of knowledge for gathering specific strings out of a text file. The hard part I failed to explain was -- How do I get the IDE to look for a particular word, like "Ethernet", for instance, and print out an IP address that follows it ? Even if that IP may not be listed for 4-5 lines.

Here is my code, so far it prints everything well.

```
sesame = open('sample1.txt', 'r'); contents = sesame.read()

for hostname in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "hostname " in hostname:
        print ("The name of the router is : " + hostname)
        break;
for version in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "version " in version:
        print ("The version of this router is : " + version)
        break;
print (" ***********************************" + "\n" + "The following allows name to IP address resolution" + "\n" )
for hostb in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "ip host lab-b " in hostb:
        print (hostb)
        break;
for hostc in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "ip host lab-c " in hostc:
        print (hostc)
        break;    
for hostd in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "ip host lab-d " in hostd:
        print (hostd)
        break;    
for hoste in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "ip host lab-e " in hoste:
        print (hoste)
        break;
for hostf in open('sample1.txt'):
    if "ip host lab-f " in hostf:
        print (hostf)
        break;
```

Comment: Gosh, why those semicolons `;`, you don't need them.

Comment: Gosh, why the constant reopening of the same file. Why not read this information *once*?

Comment: Regex may be a good solution to your "How do I get the IDE to look for a particular word, like "Ethernet", for instance, and print out an IP address that follows it ? Even if that IP may not be listed for 4-5 lines." I'll type up an answer but it looks like there are more issues than just this! What, exactly, are you trying to pull from the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're generally better off editing existing questions and flagging for reopening than asking new questions.

Comment: inspectorG4dget, thank you for taking your time to write that. It's not printing anything for me when I input my .txt file though.

Comment: @user3111629 You should make that comment in response to inspectorG4dget's answer, or he may not notice it.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget thank you for taking your time to write that. It's not printing anything for me when I input my .txt file though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    getip = False
    iface = None
    interfaces = ['ethernet']  # or whatever other interfaces' IPs you want
    props = ['ip address']  # include IOS, name of the router, etc
    for line in  infile:
        if any(line.startswith(w) for w in interface):
            iface = line.split(None, 1)[0]
            getip = True
        elif getip:
            for prop in props:
                if line.startswith(prop)
                    getip = False
                    print(iface, ":", prop, line.replace(prop, '').split(None, 1)[0])
                    break
```

Comment: Hey Inspector, it's not printing anything for me when I input my .txt file though.

Comment: Please post a sample input, and the expected output